# Remove PDF metadata (removing complete PDF metadata )

Tags: pdf, metadata

I want to remove metadata from PDF files. I have already tried to use "exiftool", "pdftk" and "qpdf" to remove the metadata (method proposed - https://gist.github.com/hubgit/6078384 ). These tools claim to remove metadata but unfortunately retain them. I used "grep -a metadata_fieldname file.pdf" option and I could retrieve the metadata value.

Is there a way to completely delete the metadata information from PDF files (delete all the objects containing metadata information).

I am using Ubuntu. When I create a PDF file using LaTeX tool (ex- pdfTeX) or LibreOffice, the tool automatically writes the information of Producer, Creator and sometimes Full banner etc.. in the metadata of the PDF file. So I am looking to remove this information from PDF files (basically the metadata information stored by the PDF creator tool).

Comment: What OS are you on, and what tools are you looking for? There are undoubtedly GUI apps that can edit (and thus remove) the metadata; and it may be possible to use python libraries. Have you tried Coherent PDF? https://community.coherentpdf.com

Comment: Please define exactly the type of metadata you want to remove. Do you only mean the metadata as specified in the PDF specification (i.e. in metadata stream associated with the document or a component of the document, and in the document information dictionary associated with the document)? Or do you also mean custom metadata added by programs in their proprietary manners? PDF is a very flexible format and allows custom additions, so those custom metadata can take many forms not recognized by tools trying to remove metadata. Probably you should share your example PDF and the metadata key...

Comment: In the case of exiftool, it's [docs on PDFs](https://exiftool.org/TagNames/PDF.html) specifically state that the changes it makes are reversible unless the file has been relinearized.  Additionally, since you are searching the raw file, some of that data you are finding may be something embedded in one of the objects embedded in the PDF, such as a font or jpg image.  You should try and check if that might be the case.

Comment: Probably you should share your example PDF and the metadata key..

Comment: @mkl u were right, the metadata I was viewing after using qpdf and pdftk was indeed associated to embedded objects and images. Thanks for the clarification :-)

Answer (score 14):

To remove all pdf information dictionary using pdftk on your ubuntu terminal, you can use the following commands:

```
pdftk file.pdf  dump_data |sed -e 's/\(InfoValue:\)\s.*/\1\ /g' | pdftk file.pdf update_info - output file_no_meta.pdf
```

Assuming file.pdf is the source file and your pdf file output as file_no_meta.pdf

Next, use the following command to remove XMP metadata:

```
exiftool -all:all= -overwrite_original file_no_meta.pdf
```

Finally, use the following command on your terminal to check for the file metadata again:

```
pdfinfo file_no_meta.pdf
```

Comment: This **does not remove** XMP metadata. I have just used `pdftk` to change the Title InfoKey, and discovered that the process stream I have to use reads the XMP metadata if present, where the title was left unchanged.

Comment: Yes, I understand what you mean, in that case, you can use exiftool to remove XMP metadata. I just added the code that can help to remove the XMP metadata from a file. Please check it and see.

Comment: @LSerni I hope my suggestion worked for you? Afterward, you choose the best answer that matches your question. Thanks!

Comment: That was not *my* question :-) -- in my own case I had to rewrite the XMP metadata, I just extracted the XML object and reinjected it in the PDF stream using xmlparse + iText.

Answer (score 3):

You can use pdftk to strip all Info and XMP metadata from a document by copying its pages into a new PDF, like this:

```
pdftk A=mydoc.pdf cat A output mydoc.no_metadata.pdf
```

Comment: Solved my problem faced while uploading latex generated pdf to arxiv.

Answer (score 0):

For

```
pdftk A=mydoc.pdf cat A output mydoc.no_metadata.pdf
```

to work, you need an older version of pdftk.

pdftk-java messes things up.